# Data added through REST API not visible in Forge

Tags: firebase

I can put and get data using the rest commands, but when I look at my Forge, that information isn't there. Likewise, I cannot get data added in Forge through my rest commands.

https://location.firebaseio-demo.com/userData.json

I can go to this site and see the data, and I can remove the .json and it takes me to a Forge view of the data I've been adding through REST, but that Forge shows a different set of data in it than the Forge I get to when I log in and view it.

It's the same location shown in both Forges, but showing different content.

Answer (score 1):

I see now. I was using ...firebaseio-DEMO.com... on my rest calls instead of just ...firebaseio...

Does appending -DEMO on the end of my own URL just create some sort of test view of my database? Is that something intentional?

Comment: -demo domains are a public read-write space--a sandbox for testing and experimenting. They do not have security rules or authentication, they can go away at any time, and are great for tinkering.